# Automatic PTR-records for computers on a windows domain?

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory, dns.ptr

Computers connected to a windows domain are accessable through `computerName.domain.tld`
Is there a way to automatically add PTR-records to these on a local AD-integrated DNS-server?
If not: why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it might not create the reverse lookup zone by default.  Take a look at this [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961414.aspx) article explaining how to setup a reverse lookup zone.

This [windowsreference.com](http://www.windowsreference.com/dns/how-to-create-dns-reverse-lookup-zone-in-windows-server-2003/) article explains how to setup the automatic PTR records.

> If you are using DHCP with DNS server you can use this with the
>   following procedure Go to Start–>Administrative tools—>DHCP This will
>   open DHCP MMC snapin now you need to right click on your DHCP select
>   properties this will bring properties windows now click on DNS tab
>   under this select “Always dynamically Update DNS A and PTR Records.